# Functions as values in a dictionary being iterated instead of being selected

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I have a function that looks similar to this:

```
def some_function(self, case, index):
    with threading.Lock:
        return{
            'case1':function1(index),
            'case2':function2(index)
        }[case]
```

And elsewhere this function is being called as such:

```
for i in range(4)
    self.module.some_function('case1', i)
```

Which should iterate function1 for indices within the specified range. Instead, both function1 and function2 are iterated for the indices. Is there a problem with the implementation above? What could be causing both function1 and function2 to be called when only a single key is given?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, this dict literal expression is evaluated first:

```
{
    'case1':function1(index),
    'case2':function2(index)
}
```

and only then the key you specify after it, is selected from it, but at that time the two functions have already executed.

So, you should do it differently: first the correct function must be selected using the `case` variable, and only after that selection the function should be executed by passing the argument to it.

There are several solutions, but here is one:

```
return [function1, function2][case == 'case2'](index)
```

Or with a dict literal:

```
return {
    'case1': function1, 
    'case2': function2
}[case](index)
```

Or with an inline `if`:

```
return function1(index) if case == 'case1' else function2(index)
```

Or avoiding the repetition of `(index)`:

```
return (function1 if case == 'case1' else function2)(index)
```

Or you can use a plain `if`:

```
if case == 'case1':
    return function1(index)
return function2(index)
```

Comment: Are you saying that I should initialize the dict, and call separately from it with return?

Comment: No, the solution I gave does not use a dict at all (but a list). The use of either is only an intermediate value. The returned value does not reflect anymore what that intermediate structure was. Is the list solution not working out for you? Anyway, the essence is that you don't pass `index`, to execute the function, until you have narrowed the choice down to the desired function. See the addition to my answer.

Comment: I see, that makes more sense. Unfortunately `function1` and `function2` was designed to take a string as its argument, and the string is constructed partially using `str(index)`. It might be impossible to pass `index` after selecting the function.

If I make it such that both keys call the same function, would I still need to pass `index` after narrowing down which key is being used?

Comment: Nevermind, I see that it would not work as the dict literal expression is still evaluated first. I will see if I can come up with a work-around. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I don't see what the problem is. You can pass whatever argument (string, complex expression, ...) to the final selected function. So instead of the final `(index)`, you can do `(str(index))`, or any other expression, as long as you put it in parentheses (which is the syntax for calling a function).